# Jumpiness in UIScrollView (when removing top 'page')

Tags: ios, swift, uiscrollview

I'm building a prototype of a custom, paged `UIScrollView` whose core functionality is to remove the current/topmost 'page' as soon as it passes the top view boundary (i.e. goes completely out of view). This has been working fine with rather primitive code in the scrollView's delegate, but continuous swiping from the second 'page' onwards causes a glitch whereby the scrollView jumps to the next page very quickly. This continues until the scrollView is moved in the opposite direction.

I am using playing card images in my image array as the *pages*, and since the core user functionality is to be quickly swiping through these card pages, it is very poor UX to have a glitchy/fast response.

For example please see the video below:

(approx. 10 secs - excuse the replaying)
[image]

My code is:

```
func scrollViewDidScroll(scrollView: UIScrollView) {

        if (scrollView.contentOffset.y >= scrollView.frame.height) {
            print("CATCH at \(scrollView.contentOffset.y)")

            // Handle 'cards' UIImageView array directly
            self.cards.first?.removeFromSuperview()
            self.cards.removeFirst()
            for cardImage in self.cards {
                cardImage.frame = CGRectOffset(cardImage.frame, 0, -cardImage.frame.height)
            }

            // Resize the scrollView's contentView and coordinates
            scrollView.contentSize = CGSizeMake(scrollView.frame.width, scrollView.contentSize.height - scrollView.frame.height)
            scrollView.setContentOffset(CGPointMake(0, 0), animated: false)

            print("new content offset: \(scrollView.contentOffset.y)")
        }
    }
```

In the above code, when the view starts to 'glitch' (i.e. scroll very fast), the 'CATCH' value of `contentOffset.y` exceeds the view height — and when it is 'smooth' the 'CATCH' value is exactly the page height (what we would expect from a normal pagination animation); therefore, I can only assume it is catching the view too late as it is going too quickly (?)

The glitching is stopped by moving the scrollView in the opposite direction a little first, suggesting that something about the scrollView's animation or velocity is reset when doing so.

I've tried many different methods in the `scrollViewDidEndDecelerating` delegate, such as resetting the scrollView's `panGestureRecognizer` and `scrollEnabled`, to no avail.

Appreciate pointers here!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After experimenting with `UIScrollViewDelegate`'s various delegate functions, I've discovered that manipulating `scrollViewDidScroll` at a point where the scrollView naturally stops (such as the end of the next page in a paged scrollView) bypasses `scrollViewDidEndDecelerating` in some circumstances (such as this one), and causes it to mis-fire once scrolling starts again, which is what was causing the page-jumping above.

The solution was to move my code to `scrollViewDidEndDecelerating` and to handle the 'live' scroll event edits only in `scrollViewDidScroll`.